# Wordpress: display categories and taxonomies with custom archive

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to display

- category *News* (that contains only standard posts) with `archive.php`

and

- category *X* (that contains only custom post type) or taxonomy *Y* with `archive-custom.php`

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the template-hierarchy, I'm sure it is possible:

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Following the hierarchy convention, it should be:

- `category-x.php` -> is automatically used for that category
- `taxonomy-y.php` -> is automatilally used for that taxonomy
- `archive.php` will be used for News if no more specific template is
  available.

Comment: In this way I have to create a php file for each categories and taxonomy? I have many of them, and I use the same template to display them. Then I will have many identical files... this is a little bit "dirty"...

Comment: @FredKafka, you can use [load_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to include the same content in different templates

Comment: The hierarchy just looks first for the slug, if that template does not exist, it just falls back to the next template, all the way back to `archive.php`.

Comment: More about the template hierarchy of WP: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I think I will use `archive.php` for all the categories/taxonomies except the News category. For that I will make a `category-news.php` file. is it right?

Comment: That sounds like it would work perfectly, if `news` is the slug of that category of course.